# Android httpclient multipart post

Tags: android, post, apache-httpclient-4.x

Good evening.

I have a post request like this

```
-----------------------------17911109517875 Content-Disposition: form-data;
name="PERSON*1[F*2][2664]" value1 
-----------------------------17911109517875 Content-Disposition: form-data; 
name="PERSON*1[I*3][2776]" value2 
-----------------------------17911109517875 Content-Disposition: form-data;  
name="PERSON*1[O*4][2778]" value3
```

And trying to send it from android device via HttpClient.

```
public String doMultipartPost(String url, List<NameValuePair> urlParameters) {

    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
    HttpProtocolParams.setUserAgent(client.getParams(), "My funcy UA");

    MultipartEntity entity = new 
            MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    for (NameValuePair nvp : urlParameters) {
        try {
            entity.addPart(nvp.getName(), new StringBody(nvp.getValue()));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    request.setEntity(entity);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request, localContext);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "post";

}
```

But how about `-----------------------------17911109517875 Content-Disposition: form-data;` 
Is it set automatically by MultipartEntity or I should write it somewhere in the code ? This code doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar code working in a personal project. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971628/how-to-pass-string-variable-in-multipartentity) can give you some guidance too.

Boundaries are set automatically by the library so you don't have to take care of them, depending the syntax on the HttpMultipartMode. I used the default STRICT mode.

Have you added the [additional libraries needed](http://blog.tacticalnuclearstrike.com/2010/01/using-multipartentity-in-android-applications/)? Those worked for me...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.james</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-mime4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Can you provide more information about the error: traces in logcat or logs on the server?